# Global emphsize the theorem name

Tags: theorems

I would like to global define the `theorem` environment such that the name of the thereom (like `ABC` in the following example) is emphasized (either `\textit` or `\textbf`), how can I do that?

I know I can do it one by one, but it would be more convienent to define it globally.

```
\begin{theorem}[ABC]
\end{theorem}
```

Comment: What theorem package are you using? Please create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that we can work with.

Comment: Based on the general inquiry, I think you'll find what you need in terms of customization in one of the following posts: [How to make the optional title of a theorem bold with `amsthm`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43966/5764); [How to remove brackets from the optional title in `amsthm`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52621/5764); [How can I make a custom theorem for a definition?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/83446/5764)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `amsthm`, you can declare a new theorem style using `\newtheoremstyle`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}
  {\topsep}%
  {\topsep}%
  {\itshape}%
  {}%
  {\bfseries}
  {.}
  {.5em}%
  {\thmname{#1}~\thmnumber{#2}\thmnote{ (#3)}}%
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[ABC]
test
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to use the [`thmtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) package as a front-end for `amsthm` or `ntheorem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\declaretheoremstyle[notefont=\bfseries,bodyfont=\itshape]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[style=mystyle]{theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}[ABC]
test
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

I used `\bfseries` for the annotation font, but you can use `\itshape` instead if italics are preferred,

Answer (score 0):

With the `ntheorem` package, you use a `theoremstyle`, that describes the general layout, and specify font characteristics, numbering, position of margin, separator, endtheorem mark, &c. A specification is valid for all subsequently declared "new theorems", until another specification replaces it. You can define new theoremstyles, either with the own syntax of the package or with the help of the `mathtools`package.

There are 9 predefined theorem styles; plain, break, change, margin, change break, marginbreak, nonumberplain, nonumberbreak and empty. Framed or shaded theorems are also possible

Here is an example, just to show how it works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath} % Or mathtools

\usepackage[thref,amsmath,endmarks]{ntheorem}

        \theoremstyle{plain}

         \theoremheaderfont{\bfseries}
         \theorembodyfont{\itshape}
         \theoremseparator{.}
                \newtheorem{Thm}{Theorem}
                \newtheorem{Prop}{Proposition}

         \theoremheaderfont{\scshape\upshape}
         \theorembodyfont{\upshape}
                \newtheorem{Def}{Definition}

        \theoremstyle{break}
            \theoremseparator{:}
            \newtheorem{Example}{Example}

        \theoremstyle{nonumberplain}
            \theoremsymbol{\square}
             \newtheorem{Proof}{Proof}

     \begin{document}
      ...................................
```